# Why is cd. even useful

Tags: unix

I am trying to understand why would anyone use `cd .`
the `cd ..` command will take you to your parent directory.
the `cd` command will take you to your home directory
the `cd .` takes you to your 'pwd'

I can see a use for the first two, but none for the last one. 
Anyone can share their experience with `cd .`?

Comment: Perhaps it isn't useful...

Comment: Perhaps, but I would assume someone put it there for a reason

Comment: A link to your current directory exists to make it easier to reference files and executables  rooted at the current subdirectory. E.g. "./Files/user1887377/Documents/myFile" There's other uses I'm sure you can think of. A consequence of this then, is, well, a link to your current directory exists within itself. the "cd" command works exactly as it should, only it's useless in this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cd .` is seldom useful, but `.` has many uses. For instance, some versions of `find` require the directory argument and don't set it to `.` as the default, so you have to type `find .`. Or to run a script from `.`, you'd do `./script.sh`. Or to list the permissions on the current directory, you can do `ls -ld .`.

The one use I've ever had for `cd .` is if the directory you're in has been deleted and recreated. Many commands start mysteriously failing until you type `cd .` to go to the "new" incarnation of the directory.

Answer (score 1):

The `cd` command can take any format of relative path, including `.`.

It would not make sense to add a special exception to `cd` that disallows `.`.

The `.` relative path is useful for other commands; for example, it's the simplest way to refer to the current directory.